# Is there a way to fill blank columns by matching terms from one column to another, when the terms are not exact?

Tags: r, rbind

I have used `rbind` to combine two datasets into a 828 x 5 dataframe, called **vegetation**.
 Here is an example of my current dataframe:

```
site                           year    sos    eos    vegetation
EPIC_alligatorriver.csv        2016    176    301
EPIC_alligatorriver.csv        2018    164    291
Landsat_alligatorriver.csv     2016    170    303
Pheno_alligatorriver.csv       2017    152    288
Landsat_NEON.BART42.csv        2017    115    290
Pheno_NEON.BART42.csv          2017    120    290
alligatorriver.csv             NA      NA     NA     deciduous broadleaf
NEON.BART42.csv                NA      NA     NA     mixed forest
```

Here is what I need

```
site                           year    sos    eos    vegetation
EPIC_alligatorriver.csv        2016    176    301    deciduous broadleaf
EPIC_alligatorriver.csv        2018    164    291    deciduous broadleaf
Landsat_alligatorriver.csv     2016    170    303    deciduous broadleaf
Pheno_alligatorriver.csv       2017    152    288    deciduous broadleaf
Landsat_NEON.BART42.csv        2017    115    290    mixed forest
Pheno_NEON.BART42.csv          2017    120    290    mixed forest
alligatorriver.csv             NA      NA     NA     deciduous broadleaf
NEON.BART42.csv                NA      NA     NA     mixed forest
```

Basically, I need to fill in the blank vegetation column by matching the correct vegetation type based on the site name.

I can also remove the rbind and have all of the vegetation data in a completely different two column dataframe

```
site                     vegetation
alligatorriver.csv       deciduous broadleaf
konza.csv                grassland
merbleue.csv             wetland
NEON.BART42.csv          mixed forest
```

if that makes it easier.  There are 7 vegetation types total, and 99 sites over a three year period (2016, 2017, 2018).  Any help is appreciated!

```
df1 (partial): structure(list(site = c("EPIC_alligatorriver.csv", "EPIC_alligatorriver.csv", 
"EPIC_alligatorriver.csv", "EPIC_arbutuslakeinlet.csv", "EPIC_arbutuslakeinlet.csv", 
"EPIC_arbutuslakeinlet.csv", "EPIC_archboldavir.csv", "EPIC_archboldavir.csv", 
"EPIC_archboldavir.csv", "EPIC_archboldavirx.csv"), year = c(2016L, 2017L, 2018L, 2016L, 2017L, 2018L, 2016L, 
2017L, 2018L, 2016L), sos = c(117, 111, 122, 147, 145, 144, 98, 156, 
114, 98), eos = c(294, 294, 274, 276, 271, 274, 315, 295, 307, 315), vegetation = c("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "")), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"), class = "data.frame")
```

```
df2: structure(list(vegetation = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 4L, 7L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 2L, 4L, 7L, 2L, 
4L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 
1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("agriculture", 
"deciduous broadleaf", "evergreen needlefeaf", "grassland", "mixed forest", 
"shrub", "wetland"), class = "factor"), site = structure(1:99, .Label = c("alligatorriver", 
"arbutuslakeinlet", "archboldavir", "archboldavirx", "archboldpnot", 
"archboldpnotx", "arsmnswanlake1", "ashburnham", "bartlettir", 
"bostoncommon", "bullshoals", "burnssagebrush", "canadaOBS", 
"caryinstitute", "cperuvb", "downerwoods", "dukehw", "goodnow", 
"grandteton", "harvard", "harvardbarn", "harvardbarn2", "harvardfarmsouth", 
"harvardhemlock", "harvardhemlock2", "harvardlph", "howland1", 
"howland2", "hubbardbrook", "huyckpreserveny", "jerbajada", "jernort", 
"kansas", "kelloggcorn", "kendall", "kingmanfarm", "konza", "lacclair", 
"laclaflamme", "laurentides", "lethbridge", "lostcreek", "luckyhills", 
"mandanh5", "mandani2", "mead1", "mead2", "mead3", "meadpasture", 
"merbleue", "missouriozarks", "montebondonegrass", "montebondonepeat", 
"morganmonroe", "nationalelkrefuge", "ncssm", "NEON.BART33", 
"NEON.BART42", "NEON.DELA33", "NEON.DSNY33", "NEON.HARV33", "NEON.HARV42", 
"NEON.JERC33", "NEON.JERC42", "NEON.LENO33", "NEON.ONAQ33", "NEON.ORNL33", 
"NEON.ORNL42", "NEON.RMNP33", "NEON.SERC33", "NEON.TREE33", "NEON.TREE42", 
"NEON.UNDE33", "NEON.WOOD33", "ninemileprairie", "northattkeboroma", 
"oakville", "proctor", "queens", "readingma", "rosemountnprs", 
"russellsage", "sanford", "sevilletagrass", "sevilletashrub", 
"shalehillsczo", "southerngreatplains", "stjones", "sweetbriar", 
"sweetbriargrass", "sylvania", "tonzi", "umichbiological2", "usgseros", 
"usmpj", "uwmfieldsta", "warrenwilson", "willowcreek", "worcester"
), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-99L))
```

Comment: Can you add the output of `dput` so we can reproduce the data without having to type it in?

Comment: @dario could you give me more info on how to do that? Do I just `dput(vegetation)` into the console and copy paste the output?

Comment: If you add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610). you could make it easier for others to find and test a answer to your question. That way you can help others to help you!

Comment: @dario great, thank you! I will work on getting that added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using `match()` using the site columns in the two dataframes using `sub()` to remove the prefix from the first data.frame:

```
df$vegetation <- df2$vegetation[match(sub("^.*_", "", df$site), df2$site)]

df

                        site year sos eos          vegetation
1    EPIC_alligatorriver.csv 2016 176 301 deciduous broadleaf
2    EPIC_alligatorriver.csv 2018 164 291 deciduous broadleaf
3 Landsat_alligatorriver.csv 2016 170 303 deciduous broadleaf
4   Pheno_alligatorriver.csv 2017 152 288 deciduous broadleaf
5    Landsat_NEON.BART42.csv 2017 115 290        mixed forest
6      Pheno_NEON.BART42.csv 2017 120 290        mixed forest
```

Data:

```
df <- structure(list(site = c("EPIC_alligatorriver.csv", "EPIC_alligatorriver.csv", 
                              "Landsat_alligatorriver.csv", "Pheno_alligatorriver.csv", "Landsat_NEON.BART42.csv", 
                              "Pheno_NEON.BART42.csv"), year = c(2016L, 2018L, 2016L, 2017L, 
                                                                 2017L, 2017L), sos = c(176L, 164L, 170L, 152L, 115L, 120L), eos = c(301L, 
                                                                                                                                     291L, 303L, 288L, 290L, 290L), vegetation = c("deciduous broadleaf", 
                                                                                                                                                                                   "deciduous broadleaf", "deciduous broadleaf", "deciduous broadleaf", 
                                                                                                                                                                                   "mixed forest", "mixed forest")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")

df2 <- structure(list(site = c("alligatorriver.csv", "konza.csv", "merbleue.csv", 
                               "NEON.BART42.csv"), vegetation = c("deciduous broadleaf", "grassland", 
                                                                  "wetland", "mixed forest")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                   -4L))
```

Comment: I separated the original file into the two dataframes and applied this, but it just filled the vegetation column in df with "NA".  Any possible reason why?  I am happy to post the entirety of both dataframes if that is helpful.

Comment: One reason is that there were no exact matches found.  You don't need to post the data frames in their entirety if they're big, just enough to illustrate the problem.  Use `dput(df)`. Post the code you used that resulted in NAs too.

Comment: Posted the dataframes.  I used `df$vegetation <- df2$vegetation[match(sub("^.*_", "", df$site), df2$site)]`

Comment: I see my issue now...the original site names in df2 do not have .csv at the end, of course!  Can I add something into your previous recommendation to take care of this?  Thank you for all your help!

Comment: That's correct - you can use `df1$vegetation <- df2$vegetation[match(tools::file_path_sans_ext(sub("^.*_", "", df1$site)), df2$site)]`.